# How to add created objects to arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've created objects already in the canvas method. But I need help on how to create an arraylist and to add these four objects to the arraylist so that they will constantly appear. I've looked at the [arraylist](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) Heres the code, any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class BouncingBallView extends View {

    private int xMin = 0;          // This view's bounds
    private int xMax;
    private int yMin = 0;
    private int yMax;
    private int xMin1 = 0;          // This view's bounds
    private int xMax1;
    private int yMin1 = 0;
    private int yMax1;
    private int xMin2 = 0;          // This view's bounds
    private int xMax2;
    private int yMin2 = 0;
    private int yMax2;
    private int xMin3 = 0;          // This view's bounds
    private int xMax3;
    private int yMin3 = 0;
    private int yMax3;

    private float ballRadius = 80;
    private float ballRadius2 = 80;// Ball's radius
    private float ballX = ballRadius + 20;  // Ball's center (x,y)
    private float ballY = 10;//ballRadius + 40;
    private float ballX1= ballRadius2 + 30;
    private float ballY1 = 15;
    private float ballX2 = ballRadius + 20;  // Ball's center (x,y)
    private float ballY2 = 10;//ballRadius + 40;
    private float ballX3 = ballRadius + 20;  // Ball's center (x,y)
    private float ballY3 = 10;//ballRadius + 40;
    private float ballSpeedX = 50;  // Ball's speed (x,y)
    private float ballSpeedX1= 25;
    private float ballSpeedY = 30;
    private float ballSpeedY1= 15;
    private float ballSpeedX2 = 40;  // Ball's speed (x,y)
    private float ballSpeedX3= 20;
    private float ballSpeedY2 = 20;  // Ball's speed (x,y)
    private float ballSpeedY3= 10;
    private RectF ballBounds;      // Needed for Canvas.drawOval
    private RectF ballBounds2;
    private RectF ballBounds3;  
    private RectF ballBounds4;  
    private Paint paint;           // The paint (e.g. style, color) used for drawing

    // Constructor
    public BouncingBallView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ballBounds = new RectF();
        ballBounds2 = new RectF();
        ballBounds3 = new RectF();
        ballBounds4 = new RectF();
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    // Called back to draw the view. Also called by invalidate().
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ballBounds2.set(10, ballY1, 50, ballY1+40);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(ballBounds2,6,6, paint);
        // Draw the ball
        ballBounds.set(10, ballY, 50, ballY+40);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(ballBounds,6,6, paint);

        ballBounds3.set(10, ballY2, 50, ballY2+40);
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(ballBounds3,6,6, paint);

        ballBounds4.set(10, ballY3, 50, ballY3+40);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(ballBounds4,6,6, paint);

        // Update the position of the ball, including collision detection and reaction.
        update();

        // Delay
        try {  
            Thread.sleep(30);  
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }      
        invalidate();  // Force a re-draw
    }


    // Detect collision and update the position of the ball.

    private void update() {
        // Get new (x,y) position
        //ballX += ballSpeedX;
        ballY += ballSpeedY;
        ballY1 += ballSpeedY1;
        ballY2 += ballSpeedY2;
        ballY3 += ballSpeedY3;
        // Detect collision and react
        //  if (ballX + ballRadius > xMax) {
        //   ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        // ballX = xMax-ballRadius;
        //   } 
        // else if (ballX - ballRadius < xMin) {
        //     ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        //   ballX = xMin+ballRadius;
        // }

        if (ballY + ballRadius > yMax) {
            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
            ballY = yMax - ballRadius;
        } else if (ballY - ballRadius < yMin) {
            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
            ballY = yMin + ballRadius;
        }
        if (ballY1 + ballRadius2 > yMax1) {
            ballSpeedY1 = -ballSpeedY1;
            ballY1 = yMax1 - ballRadius2;
        } else if (ballY1 - ballRadius2 < yMin1) {
            ballSpeedY1 = -ballSpeedY1;
            ballY1 = yMin1 + ballRadius2;
        }
        if (ballY2 + ballRadius2 > yMax2) {
            ballSpeedY2 = -ballSpeedY2;
            ballY2 = yMax2 - ballRadius2;
        } else if (ballY2 - ballRadius2 < yMin2) {
            ballSpeedY2 = -ballSpeedY2;
            ballY2 = yMin2 + ballRadius2;
        }
        if (ballY3 + ballRadius2 > yMax3) {
            ballSpeedY3 = -ballSpeedY3;
            ballY3 = yMax3 - ballRadius2;
        } else if (ballY3 - ballRadius2 < yMin3) {
            ballSpeedY3 = -ballSpeedY3;
            ballY3 = yMin3 + ballRadius2;
        }
    }

    // Called back when the view is first created or its size changes.
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        // Set the movement bounds for the ball
        xMax = w-1;
        yMax = h-1;
        xMax1= w-1;
        yMax1= h-1;
        xMax2 = w-1;
        yMax2 = h-1;
        xMax3 = w-1;
        yMax3 = h-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a canvas method.

Answer (score 0):

This code goes inside of your constructor.

```
ArrayList<RectF> ballBoundArray = new ArrayList<RectF>();
ballBoundArray.add(ballBounds);
ballBoundArray.add(ballBounds2);
ballBoundArray.add(ballBounds3);
ballBoundArray.add(ballBounds4);
```

Edit: If you want the array list to be accessible outside of the constructor, define it as a private or public variable with the other ballbounds.